# Automatizar tarefas com Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, apache, cron, scheduler

Bom dia Pessoal.

Estou precisando criar algumas tarefas no meu sistema, que sejam executadas automaticamente (tal como uma Cron Job).
Exemplo: Todo dia o sistema mandar um email para os clientes do sistema com o valor de suas cobranças, e as que estão perto de vencer.

Dei uma lida aqui no Scheduler, mas a documentação do laravel não deixou claro para mim como isso funciona.
Alguem saberia me explicar melhor como funciona este recurso? como eu criar tarefas de acordo com minha necessidade?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comece por adicionar ao cron uma entrada que rode o comando `php artisan schedule:run` a cada minuto.

Então pode usar de várias maneiras:

**Comandos:**

```
$schedule->command('cache:clear')
    ->hourly()
    ->sendOutputTo($filePath)
    ->emailOutputTo('john@doe.com');
```

**Métodos de uma classe:**

```
$schedule->call('SomeClass@method')->dailyAt('10:00');
```

**Função anônima:**

```
$schedule->call(function(){
    //.. 
})->everyThirtyMinutes();
```

**Comando de terminal:**

```
$schedule->terminal('gulp task')->fridays()->when(function(){ 
    return true;
});
```

Fonte: https://laravel-news.com/2014/11/laravel-5-scheduler/