# Como criar um cron no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, cron

Tenho de criar um Cron no Laravel para enviar emails a cada 24h.
Devo carregar no email dados do banco. 
Portanto após uma consulta no banco o cron deve enviar o email com os dados da consulta.

Comment: Uma das opções seria trabalhar com **Task Scheduling**. Documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling. Veja essa resposta aqui no StackOverflow: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53587/automatizar-tarefas-com-laravel-5

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Para criar `CRON` no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) siga os seguintes passos:

Primeiro crie um command da seguinte forma:

```
php artisan make:command ExampleCron --command=example:cron
```

dentro desse arquivo que foi criado na pasta `app/Console/Commands/ExampleCron.php`.

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DB;
class ExampleCron extends Command
{
  
    protected $signature = 'example:cron';
  
    protected $description = 'Command E-mail';
  
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    // aqui você coloca a lógica do seu processo
    // pode utilizar todos os recursos do Laravel
    public function handle()
    {
        \DB::table('emails')->get(); // pega os e-mails
        // siga o código de sua preferencia
        // executando as funções de envio de e-mail
        $this->info('Example Cron comando rodando com êxito');
    }
}
```

Altere as variáveis `$signature` e `$description` conforme exemplo e no método `handle()` a lógica do processo.

Segundo, para registrar esse `command` entre na pasta e arquivo `app/Console/Kernel.php` e abra o `Kernel.php` para adicionar no `array` do `$commands` adicione mais o `command` criado.

```
namespace App\Console;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\Inspire::class,
        Commands\ExampleCron::class,
    ];
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();

        $schedule->command('example:cron')->daily(); // email diários
    }
}
```

Terceiro, agora adicione essa linha no seu arquivo `cron`

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Pode ser configurado de várias formas e vários horário, exemplo quadro:

## Schedule Frequency Options

| Method | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `->cron('* * * * * *');` | Run the task on a custom Cron schedule |
| `->everyMinute();` | Run the task every minute |
| `->everyFiveMinutes();` | Run the task every five minutes |
| `->everyTenMinutes();` | Run the task every ten minutes |
| `->everyFifteenMinutes();` | Run the task every fifteen minutes |
| `->everyThirtyMinutes();` | Run the task every thirty minutes |
| `->hourly();` | Run the task every hour |
| `->hourlyAt(17);` | Run the task every hour at 17 mins past the hour |
| `->daily();` | Run the task every day at midnight |
| `->dailyAt('13:00');` | Run the task every day at 13:00 |
| `->twiceDaily(1, 13);` | Run the task daily at 1:00 & 13:00 |
| `->weekly();` | Run the task every week |
| `->monthly();` | Run the task every month |
| `->monthlyOn(4, '15:00');` | Run the task every month on the 4th at 15:00 |
| `->quarterly();` | Run the task every quarter |
| `->yearly();` | Run the task every year |
| `->timezone('America/New_York');` | Set the timezone |

<sup>Fonte: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#defining-schedules</sup>

***Exemplo:*** [obtido e referencia no link](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/example-of-cron-job-in-laravel-5example.html) (***fonte***: http://itsolutionstuff.com)

A sua pergunta [tem e-mail, aqui no site já tem um exemplo minimo, segue a mesma lógica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143844/envio-de-e-mail-com-laravel-5-2), siga esse exemplo básico que pode ajudar a entender o processo.

***Referencias***

- [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction)
- [Example of Cron Job in Laravel 5](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/example-of-cron-job-in-laravel-5example.html)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67644/discussion-between-alexjosesilva-and-virgilio-novic).

Comment: Para editar o arquivo cron e adicionar uma linha use: crontab -e