# Como testar o cron no laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

Criei um cron para envio de email a cada período de tempo.
Porém como testar o funcionamento ?

**Codigo**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;
namespace App\Console\Commands\EnvioEmailBlCron;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class envioEmailBIcron extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'envioEmailBI:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command Email';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       //Pegar os dados no banco
        $sql = ' select * from payments as P, receipts as R ';
        $sql .= ' where P.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND P.created_at < CURRENT_DATE -1';
        $sql .= ' OR R.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND R.created_at < CURRENT_DATE -1';

        //pega os dados no banco
        $dados = \DB::select($sql);

        //envio email
        Mail::send('emails.BI', $dados, function ($message) {
            $message->to(Input::get('email'));
        }); 


       // executando as funções de envio de e-mail
       $this->info('Example Cron comando rodando com êxito');
    }
}
```

**ConsoleKernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Units;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel;

class ConsoleKernel extends Kernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //Commands\Inspire::class,
        Commands\EnvioEmailBICron::class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule $schedule
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        //configuração do cron
        $schedule->command('inspire')->dailyAt('01:00'); 
        $schedule->command('EnvioEmailBICron:cron')->daily(); // email diários
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na sua classe de comandos tem o comando que deve ser acionado da seguinte forma:

```
class ExampleCron extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'envioEmailBI:cron';

    protected $description = 'Command E-mail';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    // aqui você coloca a lógica do seu processo
    // pode utilizar todos os recursos do Laravel
    public function handle()
    {
        //Pegar os dados no banco
         $sql = ' select * from payments as P, receipts as R ';
         $sql .= ' where P.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND P.created_at < CURRENT_DATE -1';
         $sql .= ' OR R.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND R.created_at < CURRENT_DATE -1';

         //pega os dados no banco
         $dados = \DB::select($sql);

         //envio email
         Mail::send('emails.BI', $dados, function ($message) {
            $message->to(Input::get('email'));
         }); 


        // executando as funções de envio de e-mail
        $this->info('Example Cron comando rodando com êxito');
    }
}
```

#### Commando:

```
php artisan envioEmailBI:cron
```

Esse comando serve como teste primário, sem ter a inclusão na Cron do servidor, é mesmo para teste, é muito útil, funcionando está ok o processo. [Agora é só adicionar ao Cron como foi explicado na resposta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249173/como-criar-um-cron-no-laravel/249419#249419).

> `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: estou recebendo a mensagem:  Class App\Units\Commands\Inspire does not exist

Comment: apos remover uma linha de codigo Commands\Inspire::class do 
C

Comment: consoleKernel recebi essa mensagem

Comment: [ReflectionException]                                     
  Class App\Units\Commands\envioEmailBIcron does not exist

Comment: Tem que colocar o namespace corretamente e verificar os caminhos, dá uma olhada isso é erro local seu. @alexjosesilva

Comment: o nome da classe é esse: envioEmailBIcron

Comment: O nome da classe já está fora do padrão Laravel (Laravel segue algumas nomenclaturas é bem legal porque isso coloca o código numa igualdade e facilidade de manutenção) o nome correto deveria ser `EnvioEmailBlCron` ela tem um namespace você adicionou isso com o comando `use` ? @alexjosesilva

Comment: Só lembrando que a resposta acima funciona e foi testada... com Laravel 5.3 do pacote oficial. @alexjosesilva

Comment: use não foi usado!

Comment: Tenho essa declaração EnvioEmailBICron.php : namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

Comment: OK, mas, aonde você está jogando essa classe precisa ter o namespace dela, ou seja, `App\Console\Commands\EnvioEmailBlCron` acho que falta isso que a consome. @alexjosesilva

Comment: no arquivo EnvioEmailBICron.php: namespace App\Console\Commands\EnvioEmailBlCron;

Comment: porém o erro persiste!

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque todas as classes e como você está chamando! eu não consigo pegar o erro. @alexjosesilva

Comment: adicionei o namespace e no EnvioEmailBICron.php

Comment: Adicionei o scritop  do kernel.php

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67674/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-alexjosesilva).