# TAREFA CRON LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Configurei o `cron` para executar tarefas agendadas no `Laravel` e retorna o seguinte ***erro***:

> `[16-Apr-2018 15:53:02] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/bruno013/public_html/mapx/homologacao/artisan on line 33`

Comment: A versão do php é 7 e o erro persiste.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249173/como-criar-um-cron-no-laravel/249419#249419

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/como-testar-o-cron-no-laravel/249590#249590

Comment: postei dois links de exemplo e funcionais, o que falta fazer na sua pergunta é colocar o código que você fez! poderia colocar?