# Rotina automatica no laravel 5.6

Tags: php

Bom dia, preciso criar um rotina  automatica no laravel para atualizar toda noite durante 4 dias depois do termino de uma atividade como faço isso usando laravel 5.6?

Comment: Já pesquisou sobre o [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling)?

Comment: sim mais a documentação não deixa muito claro, sou novo no mundo do laravel

Comment: Relacionada: [Como criar um cron no Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249173/5878)